# Xamarin.Froms throws CS0012 Error on accessing visibleBounds property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms, but I get the *Error CS0012 The type ' Rect ' is defined in an assembly que is not referenced . You must add a reference to assembly ' System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime , Version = 4.0.0.0 , when I try to use visibleBounds*

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAPhd.jpg)

Comment: When do you get this error? Is it in Windows Project or Shared/PCL project?

Comment: Sometimes Xamarin Studio outputs "Intellisense" errors like this but the project compiles and runs fine, maybe it's a similar bug?